# Overlay drawing in Hardware

Tags: vhdl

In particular its a simple mouse cursor. I have implemented this in software but I'm having difficulty doing this in hardware. In software I could store the bitmap as a constant array then reference it to obtain the necessary color information for the vga to display. I was trying a similar approach in hardware but realized that constant signals only exist in simulation not in synthesis.

I'm mentally stuck inside a box and would like some advice to help get get out of it so I can finish this. I need to think in hardware, as my teachers always say.

The software went something like this:

```
 const char mouse_data{ 0xff, 0x bb ... };
 color = mouse_data[1];
 vga_write(vga_base, offset, color);
```

Comment: Someone told me to turn it into a decoder with color as the key. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thinking hardware is the number one thing to do when programming FPGAs.

So, in your software implementation your `const char` array is stored in the memory of the computer - so a solution could be to create some memory in your FPGA device, and then store it there. Most FPGAs have some sort of built-in memory, that you can infer (write your code so it automatically maps to the memory blocks) or instantiate (write your code to directly use a specific memory block type). Often you can then also specify a block of data to preload it with during configuration.

On a Xilinx chip for instance, you could add a new IP-core, choose the Xilinx Memory Generator, and generate a read-only BlockRam, preloaded with your cursor data. That'd be a possibility, although not necessarily the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

'cost' is certainly synthisisable.  So you will have to give out your code for us to see why it is not for you.

Depending on what syntax it is used in, const is implemented as a decoder/mux in most synthisised VHDL.
  What might be causing you problems is 'char' which may not be synthisisable, but there is nothing to stop you creating a type 'char' which is.

Imagine a N:1 mux where the input value of N is fixed 0 or 1 rather than a signal.  That's a const that might be used as some sort of assignment to a register input.